# Is there a way to empty cached variables in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Some of my cloud functions perform heavy computations. I'm caching results to speed up response times on subsequent calls.

I want to empty the cache when the data the computation is based on has changed.

My idea was to add a cloud function that is invoked when data has changed. This cloud function should then clear the cache.

Given that the cache is in a different scope I'm not sure how to clear the cache instances though.

Given that the information doesn't change often, I would be OK to force a cold start of the cloud function that caches results. Can I do this programmatically? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no suitable answer across the web.

My solution was to cache the variable that can change separately from the rest of the cached data, move the cache time to something lower like 30 minutes, and never cache it when the system is in preview mode.